# Solve the equation $\frac{x^3+2x}{x^2-1}=\sqrt{x^2-\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, systems-of-equations, problem-solving

$$\frac{x^3+2x}{x^2-1}=\sqrt{x^2-\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$x=?$$

I solved this but the equation $ (2x + 1) (3x ^ 4-x ^ 3 + 2x ^ 2-2x + 1) = 0 $ is formed I answer $ x =- \frac {1} {2} $ I know there is, but I couldn't do the next expression. I need help with that, or someone will solve it in a better way. I'd be happy with that.

Comment: The solution for the first factor would be $x=-1/2$.

Comment: Your wording is a bit unclear. What is "the next expression"?

Comment: @MattiP. I think he means $3x ^ 4-x ^ 3 + 2x ^ 2-2x + 1$.

Comment: **Hint :** Study the function $3x^4−x^3+2x^2−2x+1$ and show that it is always positive over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you need complex roots, too?

Comment: yes so let's see if there are any new ideas for this example other methods such as trigonometric notation or higher way please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give a different approach, note that any solution to $\frac{x^3+2x}{x^2-1}=\sqrt{x^2-\frac{1}{x}}$ must lie in $(-1,0)\cup(1,\infty)$ because the left hand side is negative on $(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,1)$ whereas the right hand side, being a square root, is always non-negative, and the expression is undefined at $x=0$ and $x=\pm1$. Now if $x\lt0$, then $3x^4-x^3+2x^2-2x+1$ is a sum of positive terms (i.e., $x^3$ and $2x$ are negative, so $-x^3$ and $-2x$ are positive), while if $x\gt1$, then

$$3x^4-x^3+2x^2-2x+1\gt3x^4-x^4+2x^2-2x^2+1=2x^4+1\gt0$$

so $3x^4-x^3+2x^2-2x+1$ has no roots in the feasible solution set for $x$. (In fact, as user's answer shows, it has no roots in $(0,1)$ either.)

Answer (score 2):

Your way is fine with a solution for $x=-\frac12$, now we have that

$$3x ^ 4-x ^ 3 + 2x ^ 2-2x + 1=x^2(3x ^ 2-x  + 1)+(x-1)^2 > 0$$

since $3x ^ 2-x  + 1>0$.

---

To find complex roots we can refer to [Quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation).